# Angular 7 component redirection without routing

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-routing

With my current Angular 7 and Firebase setup I have the following situation:

I have the main app component which shows the member area if the user is logged in or otherwise the public area. Everything is working fine, but there is a 1-2 second delay until the correct component shows after signing out or in. I don't want to use routing btw. because I want to show everything with the same URL.

Do you have an idea how I can reduce the delay and is this a good practice of doing authentication anyway?
I appreciate all your help!

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="authService.isAuthorized(); else showLogin">
  <app-member></app-member>
</div>
<ng-template #showLogin>
  <app-public></app-public>
</ng-template>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And then here the components for the member area and public area:

member.component.html:

```
<button nz-button [nzSize]="size" nzType="primary (click)="authService.logout()">Logout</button>
```

public.component.html:

```
<button nz-button [nzSize]="size" nzType="primary" (click)="authService.login()">Login</button>
```

Comment: There is no way to "reduce delay" this, the request takes as long as it takes. One option is to just show a spinner while doing request.

Comment: Also it's not recommended to call functions in template, referring to `authService.isAuthorized()` it is called on each change detection and can seriously hurt performance. You should use a variable instead.

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know. I'll better change this then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your initial approach, I suggest you to use a variable as observable that defines whether the user is authorized in or not, better than call the function authService.isAuthorized().
You can do this defining an observable property in your authservice:

AuthService.ts

```
isAuthorized() {
    ...
    this.isAuthorized.next(true);
}
isAuthorized$ = this.isAuthorized.asObservable();
```

In this way, the property will be automatically updated in your main template by doing something like this:

app.component.ts

```
authService.isAuthorized$.subscribe((response) => {
    this.isAuthorized = response;
});
```

Then you can use on your main template:

app.component.html

`<div *ngIf="isAuthorized" ; else showLogin">`

And to handle the possible wait, as AJT_82 has already commented, it would be best to put a spinner until the call has been made.

Comment: I followed your advice and changed my code. Now also the delay disappeared. Thank you very much! But I'm still curious if you can still call methods like signIn or logout directly in the components template without performance problems. They are less often called so this shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: I'm glad that this solution worked for you as you expected.
It is best practice to reference the variable from the template. Especially in this case, in which we must subscribe to the method of our service.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to do it without routing. Why do not you want to use it?
It would be that simple:
Using Angular's canActivate class on your app-routing.module.ts file.

For this, you will need to implement an authentication service that checks whether the user is loged in or not.

Example:

```
   const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: MemberComponent,
        canActivate: [YourAuthGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'public',
        component: PublicComponent
      }
    ];
    @NgModule({
      imports: [...],
      exports: [...],
      providers: [ YourAuthGuard ]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then you can put redirects from one component to another with the navigate () method of the Angular class Router.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: can I use routing without modifying the URL?

Comment: No. As you can see in the configuration that I have written, the app would have these two routes:

[host/public --> Public component]
And 
[host/ --> Member component]

Why do not you want to use routing?

Comment: I was hoping to do the login as a modal and not as a separate page.

Comment: I answer in another answer, since it is very long to write it as a comment